# Shell find line and remove following lines

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file containing entries sorted by their names in brackets:

```
[numberone]
someoption
more option
[numbertwo]
option
more option
[numberthree]
option
more option
```

I want to remove [numbertwo] and a given number of options below it, keeping everything else intact. The line to remove is inputted via a variable $toremove and the file should not have empty lines between the bracketed entries. e.g.

./remover.sh remove numbertwo

After the script has run the file should look like this:

```
[numberone]
someoption
more option
[numberthree]
option
more option
```

Comment: In which manner is "a number of options below it" defined? Other variable?

Comment: @h7r Hardcoded into the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (admittedly terribly dirty) way of solving this is the following:

`remover.sh`

```
#!env bash

REMOVED_LINES=2 # fixed number of lines to be removed, here matching example data

INPUT=$1
TO_REMOVE=$2 
LINE=$(grep -n $TO_REMOVE $INPUT | sed -e 's/:/ /' | awk '{print $1}')
LAST_LINE=$(( $LINE+$REMOVED_LINES ))
sed -e ${LINE},${LAST_LINE}d $INPUT
```

Given data:

```
$ cat > test.txt
[numberone]
someoption
more option
[numbertwo]
option
more option
[numberthree]
option
more option

$ ./remover.sh test.txt numbertwo
[numberone]
someoption
more option
[numberthree]
option
more option
```

In case `numbertwo` happens more than once in the file, the behaviour will not be correct.

Comment: this does give me the right output, now all it needs is to actually overwrite the file. Could you add that?

Comment: I would argue that the script is more flexible by NOT overwriting the file on it's own. To overwrite the file you just need to add the option `-i` to the `sed` command (last line), just before $INPUT, like this: `sed -e ${LINE},${LAST_LINE}d -i $INPUT`

Answer (score 0):

It is easier using `awk`:

```
awk -v s='numberone' 'index($0, "[" s "]"){p=1;next} p && /^\[/{p=0} !p' file
[numbertwo]
option
```

#### [Working Demo](http://ideone.com/a32tMP)

Comment: That simply outputs the whole file for me.

Comment: That's not correct. Output in my answer is what it generated with the input data you provided.

Comment: To make it more dynamic I replaced the numberone with a variable($toremove). I guess I need to change something to get that to pick up?

Comment: I can test if you update the question with the sample data you're using.

Comment: Also for passing: `variable($toremove)` try this awk command: **`awk -v s='numberone' 'index($0, s){p=1;next} p && /^\[/{p=0} !p' file`**

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** This answer is based on a past edition of the question with a different goal statement. My answer is based on the interpretation that the OP wanted to keep all lines from [numbertwo] onwards.

---

You can achieve this easily with the following one liner:

```
$ cat > test.txt
[numberone]
someoption
more option
[numbertwo]
option

$ tac test.txt | sed -e '/numbertwo/q' | tac
[numbertwo]
option
```

This will make `sed` stop when finding the pattern. As you want everything *after* and including `[numbertwo]`, the trick was to invert the file, let it keep all until `numbertwo` is found, exit immediately, then invert the content again.

Comment: This only works if `[numberone]` is the first entry. What if there are entries _before_ `[numberone]`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf This is not correct. I even tested. What makes you think so? There's no dependence on `numberone` whatsoever. Only depends on the fact that `numbertwo` be the last one, but this, if I understood the OP right, is exactly the case.

Comment: This is what I tried: `{ tac | sed -e '/numbertwo/q' | tac; } < <( printf '%s\n' '[numberzero]' stuff '[numberone]' someoption 'more option' '[numbertwo]' option '[numberthree]' 'more stuff')`. It seems your command discards everything before a line matching `numbertwo`. OP's requirement is to _remove `[numberone]`'s entry and its options_. But as I commented below, OP's requirement is not clear as it's also mentioned that _only `[numbertwo]` and its options should be preserved_.

Comment: Which means I cannot remove numbertwo if a numberthree entry is present. I simply want to remove numbertwo and a given number of lines below it and keep everything else.

Comment: @user2280032 your question is in fact not clear: you mention on the one hand that you want to remove `[numberone]` and its options, and on the other hand that you only want to preserve `[numbertwo]` and its options. What should the behavior be if there are more than two entries?

Comment: @user2280032 The question seems to have been edited with a different goal statement. My answer is based on the interpretation that the OP wanted to keep all lines from `[numbertwo]` onwards. Others seem to have answered based on the same understanding.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I can't really spot the reason for what you say, but as I try `printf '%s\n' '[numberzero]' stuff '[numberone]' someoption 'more option' '[numbertwo]' option  | tac | sed -e '/numbertwo/q ' | tac` (note that I'm not talking about `numbertree`) it produces the same result I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Let me try to clarify. Each bracketed line is an entry and each entry has 10 options below it. There can be multiple entries in one file and I want to be able to remove whole entries from the file. Meaning I only want to remove the bracketed line and 10 lines below it, leaving the other entries untouched and right below one another without empty lines between them.

Comment: I guess that we're not expecting the same behavior since OP's question isn't clear `:)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I second that :)

Comment: @user2280032 Is 10 a fixed number of lines below a group to be removed, or just one example and the number is in fact variable? Do you mind explaining the exact conditions of your scenario in the problem statement above?

Comment: @h7r yes 10 lines is fixed as the same script writes only that many lines below the bracketed entry.

Comment: @user2280032 but your example data does not match this description.